# How do I create snapshot of blob?

Tags: blob, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to implement blob storage for my logs and backups and have a question about blob snapshots.
Mainly how can i setup a script in Linux(RHEL) to take snapshots every week or so.
What i'm really having trouble is finding the command to snapshot the blob.
I tried going through documentation but it's only c# api that i found nothing on how to do it using az cli or in bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`az storage blob snapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-snapshot) to create a snapshot of a blob.

```
az storage blob snapshot --container-name
                         --name
                         [--account-key]
                         [--account-name]
                         [--auth-mode {key, login}]
                         [--connection-string]
                         [--if-match]
                         [--if-modified-since]
                         [--if-none-match]
                         [--if-unmodified-since]
                         [--lease-id]
                         [--metadata]
                         [--sas-token]
                         [--subscription]
                         [--timeout]
```

Comment: Ty, took me a long time to find this